# Algorithm to Produce an Evenly Spaced Grid

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm looking for a general algorithm for creating an evenly spaced grid, and I've been surprised how difficult it is to find!
Is this a well solved problem whose name I don't know?
Or is this an unsolved problem that is best done by self organising map?

More specifically, I'm attempting to make a grid on a 2D Cartesian plane in which the Euclidean distance between each point and 4 bounding lines (or "walls" to make a bounding box) are equal or nearly equal.
For a square number, this is as simple as making a grid with sqrt(n) rows and sqrt(n) columns with equal spacing positioned in the center of the bounding box.  For 5 points, the pattern would presumably either be circular or 4 points with a point in the middle.

I didn't find a very good solution, so I've sadly left the problem alone and settled with a quick function that produces the following grid:
[image]

Comment: What is a "wall" in this context? And how can you change whether points are equidistant just by drawing a grid around them? Consider the points A=(0,0), B=(1,1), C=(2,2). C won't be equidistant to A and B no matter what you do.

Comment: I think that the problem is not well-specified. How do you define evenly-spaced? Do you only consider closest neighbors? What are possible shapes of the walls? You can always create an evenly spaced "grid" by aligning the points evenly spaced on a straight line.

Comment: How would you arrange five points in a square ? Show us.

Comment: Can you draw an example picture?

Comment: Your use of the term "equidistant" is not well defined.  If you are given `n+1` points and want them all to be equidistant with each other, you will need to build regular n-simplex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).  I suspect this isn't what you're looking for, however.

Comment: thank you for the comments, i've updated the problem description.  does it make sense now?  if no, i'm happy to make a drawing!

Comment: @calben: I edited my answer to reflect your modifications.

Comment: Sorry still not clear to me what you want.  Do you want the *minimum* distance from any point to any other and to the walls to be as similar as possible?  That can't be it because you could just pile them all together.  But in your grid some points are near and some far from each other.

Comment: Could one phrase it as wanting the distance from one point to its nearest neighbours and the bounding box to be as equal as possible?
Or to say that if one were sampling the space in the bounding box, we want as representative as possible a sample given the number of points if we are sampling the space as if coloured by the values [x,y]?

I believe in this case wanting the distance from each point to be as small as possible to its nearest neighbours and wanting the distance from each point to be as far as possible from its nearest neighbours may give equivalent results.

Comment: @calben: I don't have time to strictly prove it, but yes, al of these optimization problems will lead to approximately the same result. I want to add that typically there is more than one optimal result due to the symmetry of the square boundary.

Comment: But in your grid example, points in the middle are close to their neighbours but far from the box?

Comment: the points in the middle are such that their average/maximum/minimum distance to their nearest neighbours is approximately equal.  those points closest to the grid have approximately equal average/maximum/minimum distance to/from their nearest points and to/from the grid, making an approximately uniform sample of the space.  (in this case it's a perfectly uniform sample of the space since the points were generated with a square number).  to clarify, when i said "and the bounding box" i meant the box was to be treated as a nearest neighbour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple general solution to this problem. A self-organizing map is  probably one of the best choices.

Another way to approach this problem is to imagine the points as particles that repel each others and that are also repelled by the walls. As an initial arrangement, you could already evenly distribute the points up to the next smaller square number - for this you already have a solution. Then randomly add the remaining points.

Iteratively modify the locations to minimize the energy function based on the total force between the particles and walls. The result will of course depend on the force law, i.e. how the force depends on the distance.

To solve this, you can use numerical methods like FEM.

A simplified and less efficient method that is based on the same principle is to first set up an estimated minimal distance, based on the square number case which you can calculate. Then iterate through all points a number of times and for each one calculate the distance to its closest neighbor. If this is smaller than the estimated distance, move your point into the opposite direction by a certain fraction of the difference.

This method will generally not lead to a stable minimum but should find an acceptable solution after a number ot iterations. You will have to experiment with the stepsize and the number of iterations.

To summarize, you have three options:

- FEM method: Efficient but difficult to implement
- Self organizing map: Slightly less efficient, medium complexity of implementation.
- Iteration described in last section: Less efficient but easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your problem is still not very clearly specified. You say you want the points to be "equidistant" yet in your example, some pairs of points are far apart (eg top left and bottom right) and the points are all different distances from the walls.

Perhaps you want the points to have equal minimum distance?  In which case a simple solution is to draw a cross shape, with one point in the centre and the remainder forming a vertical and horizontal crossed line.  The gap between the walls and the points, and the points in the lines can all be equal and this can work with any number of points.